# Django Rest Framework (Rest API): 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls, attributeerror, django-class-based-views, rest

I am trying to generate class based view by using Django Rest framework. customer_details is a django app name. There is an error when I am trying to call that view in `urls.py` is:

> \customer_details\urls.py", line 15, in  path('ca_number/',views.CustomerDetailView.as_view()), **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'**

Here is some code:

**customer_details/views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import CustomerDetailModel                                 
from .serializer import CustomerDetailSerializer 

class CustomerDetailView(APIView):


def get(self, request, ca_number):#get all
    if request.user.has_perm('customer_details.view_customerdetail'):
        data = CustomerDetailModel.get_object(ca_number)
        serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response('Denied_msg', status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
       

def get(self, request, ca_number, format=None):#get single customer
    try:
        return CustomerDetailModel.objects.get(pk=ca_number)
    except CustomerDetailModel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    try:
        data = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(data, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except CustomerDetailModel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    try:
        data = self.get_object(pk)
        data.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        
    except CustomerDetailModel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

**customer_details/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import CustomerDetailView
urlpatterns = [
path('ca_number/',views.CustomerDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: According to your import lines, I think that `path('ca_number/', CustomerDetailView.as_view()),` will do the trick. (you import twice views on line 3 and 4)

Comment: Where are the parameters `ca_number`, `format` and `pk` at your path? Your code won't work that way.